# How can I use docker image from its cache?

Tags: docker, buildx

I am building a container with docker buildx. When I build I am getting the message

> WARN[0000] No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load

I know if I use `load` or `push` then it will load image from cache and push it as per the flag. Let's say I didn't use any of this flag and ran

```
docker buildx build -t docker-image:latest -f Dockerfile
```

Now I ended up using the older image with same tag. How can I use the image that I have just build, I assume it should be somewhere in the cache. So how can I tar it and show it in docker images result.

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just see the image built using buildx in `docker images` since there is a chance that the image might be multi-arch; thus which arch should be showed is not something that docker client can decide on its own.

As of now `docker images` is not capable of handling multi-arch images. The reasons being the sha and size of the complete image and the one for the individual artifact for the arch might be different.

For example take a look at the image manifest for `golang:1.20.4`

```
~ ❯ docker buildx imagetools inspect golang:1.20.4 --format="{{json .Manifest}}"                                                                                                                  16s
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
  "digest": "sha256:685a22e459f9516f27d975c5cc6accc11223ee81fdfbbae60e39cc3b87357306",
  "size": 2356,
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:5099ad46335916ab90a4ce5ead4e01cb6eefc2f0296ef9f04af61b3e60f96c78",
      "size": 1585,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:b2f1829fc0659954c29f0c51c8efc48de80bec860605b8b4e4289cce928469ab",
      "size": 1584,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v5"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:30e22c4245f21ac5434442703dccc74fb8c4a27422495827dfced2534466cb4d",
      "size": 1584,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v7"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:294f80d0e466e16090256846a4411f61407457762b227e03aa7e80d6550490b7",
      "size": 1584,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "arm64",
        "os": "linux",
        "variant": "v8"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:e0ab7786e1f984d7f1f89e6c28eff90c704bca757de087b8b80403e8b58a87aa",
      "size": 1585,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "386",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:822dd9b43162456c7a9643c1566430c6802354e45b816686ec8141e37471ec9f",
      "size": 1584,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "mips64le",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:a95d8eebb2c802d2d46476c723b1302606f51c863fae1f744839bde4c9211cfe",
      "size": 1584,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "ppc64le",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:3e09a8ac7a7530f88a290397f20c3eec1c4ea62fc033e40978cb58850516736d",
      "size": 1585,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "s390x",
        "os": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:647b841b8cc8b449ebd00e2774b7fcc8753d7053dd83227c11c306d956662f00",
      "size": 3043,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "windows",
        "os.version": "10.0.20348.1726"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:8f59f4209bc31f6904389f11733928a3ad3240830f2d64c071e0ea43ebe1134b",
      "size": 3043,
      "platform": {
        "architecture": "amd64",
        "os": "windows",
        "os.version": "10.0.17763.4377"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```